# How Can I Pass a Complex Class Object to a Web API Using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I need to pass complex or List<> class object to a web API in C#, without AJAX or jQuery. This is my code I used for the API and controller.

**Web API:**

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
[HttpGet]
public void WriteBusinessObjectApiFromObj(int Pa1, string Pa2, object item)
        {
            // To Do In Function 
        }
```

**Controller:**

```
 public void WriteBusinessObjectApi(object obj)
        {


            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                var apiUrl = "api/WriteBusinessObjectApiFromObj?Pa1=1&Pa2=2";
                var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(apiUrl, obj).Result;
                client.Dispose();
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                }
            }

        }
```

I try to call the API but I can't send objects to it.

This object I try to send like:

Returned list of object from this function:

```
public List<Product> GetProductsObj()
        {
            var products = new List<Product>
            {
                new Product()
                {
                    Id = 4,
                    Name = "product 4",
                    SupProducts = new List<SupProduct>
                    {
                        new SupProduct()
                        {
                            Id = 41,
                            Name = "Sup 41"
                        },
                        new SupProduct()
                        {
                            Id = 42,
                            Name = "Sup 42"
                        },
                        new SupProduct()
                        {
                            Id = 43,
                            Name = "Sup 43"
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Product()
                {
                    Id = 5,
                    Name = "product 5",
                    SupProducts = new List<SupProduct>
                    {
                        new SupProduct()
                        {
                            Id = 51,
                            Name = "Sup 51"
                        },
                        new SupProduct()
                        {
                            Id = 52,
                            Name = "Sup 52"
                        },
                        new SupProduct()
                        {
                            Id = 53,
                            Name = "Sup 53"
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Product()
                {
                    Id = 6,
                    Name = "product 6",
                    SupProducts = new List<SupProduct>
                    {
                        new SupProduct()
                        {
                            Id = 71,
                            Name = "Sup 71"
                        },
                        new SupProduct()
                        {
                            Id = 72,
                            Name = "Sup 72"
                        },
                        new SupProduct()
                        {
                            Id = 73,
                            Name = "Sup 73"
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            return products;
        }
```

Comment: -Do you want to pass your data in the query string or in the message body?  Because normally we send post data yhrough message body.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the binder is getting confused and trying to incorrectly mix FromBody and FromURI so try wrapping all of the parameters in an object instead.  This is a better pattern anyway because you're explicitly stating what it is that makes a "request".  Note also that in the below I specify the object type rather than just saying "object".  Better to be explicit, you know the Type on both sides anyway!

```
public class WriteBusinessObjectApiFromObjRequest
{
    public int Pa1 { get; set; }
    public string Pa2 { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Item { get; set; } // change to your Type
}

[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
[HttpGet]
public void WriteBusinessObjectApiFromObj(WriteBusinessObjectApiFromObjRequest request)
{
    // To Do In Function 
}

var apiUrl = "api/WriteBusinessObjectApiFromObj";
var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(
     apiUrl, 
     new WriteBusinessObjectApiFromObj { Pa1 = 1, Pa2 = "2", Item = obj })
     .Result;
```

Here is a [cool overview of how to use parameter binding](https://damienbod.wordpress.com/2014/08/22/web-api-2-exploring-parameter-binding/) that doesn't go into any technical detail. Alternatively, here is a [much more in depth exploration of Web API parameter binding](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx)

Comment: I Try It But Not Working With Me

Comment: Updated with a bit more explanation and suggestion.  I recommend that rather than just copy-pasting, you read those links I posted.  They'll make life a lot easier when you run into other issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

Model:

```
public class Employee
{
    [Required]
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }

    public int EmployeeRollNum { get; set; }

    public EmployeeAddress EmployeeAddr { get; set; }

    public List<EmployeeAddress> AllEmployeeAddr { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeAddress
{
    //[Required]
    public string EmployeeAddressId { get; set; }

    public string EmployeeAddressName { get; set; }

    public List<int> AllNum { get; set; }
}
```

In Web API Server:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public object Get([FromUri]Employee employee)
    {
        if (employee != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Do something with the product (not shown). 

            return employee;
        }


        return employee;
    }
```

In Web Api Client:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApiConsoleApplication1
{
    public static class UrlHelpers
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// To the query string. http://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/serialize-object-into-a-query-string-with-reflection.html 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="request"> The request. </param>
        /// <param name="separator"> The separator. </param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException"> request </exception>
        public static string ToQueryString(this object request, string innerPropertyName = null, string separator = ",")
        {
            if (request == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("request");
            }

            StringBuilder propertyQuery = new StringBuilder();

            // Get all primitive properties on the object 
            var properties = request.GetType().GetProperties()
                .Where(x => x.CanRead)
                .Where(x => x.GetValue(request, null) != null)
                .Where(x => !x.PropertyType.IsClass || (x.PropertyType.IsClass && x.PropertyType.FullName == "System.String"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.GetValue(request, null));

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in properties)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(innerPropertyName))
                {
                    propertyQuery.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", Uri.EscapeDataString(kvp.Key), Uri.EscapeDataString(kvp.Value.ToString()));
                }
                else
                {
                    propertyQuery.AppendFormat("{0}.{1}={2}", Uri.EscapeDataString(innerPropertyName), Uri.EscapeDataString(kvp.Key), Uri.EscapeDataString(kvp.Value.ToString()));
                }
                propertyQuery.AppendFormat("&");
            }

            var innerClass = request.GetType().GetProperties()
                .Where(x => x.CanRead)
                .Where(x => x.GetValue(request, null) != null && x.PropertyType.IsClass && x.PropertyType.FullName != "System.String" && !(x.GetValue(request, null) is IEnumerable))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.GetValue(request, null));

            // Get names for all IEnumerable properties (excl. string) 
            var propertyCollectionNames = request.GetType().GetProperties()
                .Where(x => x.CanRead)
                .Where(x => x.GetValue(request, null) != null)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.GetValue(request, null))
                .Where(x => !(x.Value is string) && x.Value is IEnumerable)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

            // Concat all IEnumerable properties into a comma separated string 
            foreach (var kvp in propertyCollectionNames)
            {
                var valueType = kvp.Value.GetType();
                var valueElemType = valueType.IsGenericType
                                        ? valueType.GetGenericArguments()[0]
                                        : valueType.GetElementType();
                if (valueElemType.IsPrimitive || valueElemType == typeof(string)) // List of primitive value type or string
                {
                    var enumerable = kvp.Value as IEnumerable;
                    int count = 0;
                    foreach (object obj in enumerable)
                    {
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(innerPropertyName))
                        {
                            propertyQuery.AppendFormat("{0}[{1}]={2}", Uri.EscapeDataString(kvp.Key), count, Uri.EscapeDataString(obj.ToString()));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            propertyQuery.AppendFormat("{0}.{1}[{2}]={3}", Uri.EscapeDataString(innerPropertyName), Uri.EscapeDataString(kvp.Key), count, Uri.EscapeDataString(obj.ToString()));
                        }
                        count++;
                        propertyQuery.AppendFormat("&");
                    }
                }
                else if (valueElemType.IsClass) // list of class Objects
                {
                    int count = 0;
                    foreach (var className in kvp.Value as IEnumerable)
                    {
                        string queryKey = string.Format("{0}[{1}]", kvp.Key, count);
                        propertyQuery.AppendFormat(ToQueryString(className, queryKey));
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (var className in innerClass)
            {
                propertyQuery.AppendFormat(ToQueryString(className.Value, className.Key));
            }

            return propertyQuery.ToString();
        }
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public string EmployeeId { get; set; }

        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }

        public int EmployeeRollNum { get; set; }

        public EmployeeAddress EmployeeAddr { get; set; }

        public List<EmployeeAddress> AllEmployeeAddr { get; set; }
    }

    public class EmployeeAddress
    {
        //[Required]
        public string EmployeeAddressId { get; set; }

        public string EmployeeAddressName { get; set; }

        public List<int> AllNum { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            RunAsync().Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Completed");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static async Task RunAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("HostURL"));
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("AcceptType")));

                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/Values/1");
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        string val = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>();
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t", val);
                    }

                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("AcceptType")));

                    //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add()
                    // HTTP GET
                    Employee emp = new Employee();
                    emp.EmployeeId = "sri1";

                    emp.AllEmployeeAddr = new List<EmployeeAddress>();
                    EmployeeAddress lstemployeeAddr = new EmployeeAddress();
                    lstemployeeAddr.EmployeeAddressId = "Address1";

                    lstemployeeAddr.AllNum = new List<int>();
                    lstemployeeAddr.AllNum.Add(1);
                    lstemployeeAddr.AllNum.Add(2);
                    lstemployeeAddr.AllNum.Add(3);
                    emp.AllEmployeeAddr.Add(lstemployeeAddr);

                    lstemployeeAddr = new EmployeeAddress();
                    lstemployeeAddr.EmployeeAddressId = "Address2";
                    lstemployeeAddr.AllNum = new List<int>();
                    lstemployeeAddr.AllNum.Add(24);
                    lstemployeeAddr.AllNum.Add(56);
                    emp.AllEmployeeAddr.Add(lstemployeeAddr);

                    EmployeeAddress innerEmployeeAddr = new EmployeeAddress();
                    innerEmployeeAddr.EmployeeAddressId = "Addr3";
                    innerEmployeeAddr.AllNum = new List<int>();
                    innerEmployeeAddr.AllNum.Add(5);
                    innerEmployeeAddr.AllNum.Add(6);
                    emp.EmployeeAddr = innerEmployeeAddr;

                    string query = emp.ToQueryString();

                    response = await client.GetAsync("api/Values?" + query);
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        Employee product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Employee>();
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t", product.EmployeeId, product.EmployeeName);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your code a bit? code-only answers are usually not accepted because they don't serve to help others, except to give them the code that solves their specific problem.

Comment: Employee class has some complex object like List of Employee Address. To send this complex object from WebApI client to Server in HttpGet verb, We need to send this as Query string.  UrlHelpers.ToQueryString() method helps you to convert any C# Complex object to Query string.